# Displaying Collapse From A List Generated Using A Loop Only Works With First List Item

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, ember.js

I am doing a project where I collect data from a JSON file and display a bit of it on my webpage. I get the info from a JSON file and display the data on my webpage using a loop on a list tags. The list tags basically have a collapse button and the div that displays the info. I've been able to get my data correctly so that isn't the problem. The problem is when I click the data-toggle buttons from my list that displays info, they all *only* display the collapse of the first list item. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
<ul id="talk-display">
    {{#each model as |board|}}
    <li>
        <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#talk-answer" class="btn" id="talk-question">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" style="float:left"></span>
            {{board.question}}
            <br>
            <span id="talk-name">By {{board.name}}</span>
        </button>

        <div id="talk-answer" class="collapse">
            <button class="btn" id="talk-reply">Reply</button>
            <p id="talk-response">{{board.response}}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in `html` `id`s *should* be unique. However you reuse the `id` `talk-name` multiple times in the loop, so this breaks.

Assuming you have a unique `id` on your boards a simple fix could be this:

```
<ul id="talk-display">
    {{#each model as |board|}}
    <li>
        <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target={{concat "#talk-answer" board.id}} class="btn" id={{concat "talk-question" board.id}}>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" style="float:left"></span>
            {{board.question}}
            <br>
            <span id={{concat "talk-name" board.id}}>By {{board.name}}</span>
        </button>

        <div id={{concat "talk-answer" board.id}} class="collapse">
            <button class="btn" id={{concat "talk-reply" board.id}}>Reply</button>
            <p id={{concat "talk-response" board.id}}>{{board.response}}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

However since you're using ember I *strongly recommend* you to not use the bootstrap javascript features for this but implement it with ember.